# Need to optimize query

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have problems running the following query in a shared hosting server. The execution time is set to 10 secs but my query takes long and I cannot change it.

```
SELECT M.fecha_mov, -SUM(M.monto) monto, -SUM(M.interes) interes, -SUM(M.iva) iva, -SUM(M.capital) capital, 
B.banco, 
COALESCE(tg.nombre, tp.NombComp) nombreGrupo, CONCAT(nombres,' ',apellido_paterno,' ',apellido_materno) nombre, 
C.expediente, C.id_credito 
FROM movimientos M 
JOIN acreditados A ON A.id_acreditado=M.id_acreditado 
JOIN personas P ON P.id_persona=A.id_persona 
JOIN creditos C ON C.id_credito=A.id_credito 
JOIN abonos AB ON AB.id_movimiento=M.id_movimiento 
JOIN depositos_bancarios D ON D.id_deposito=AB.id_deposito 
JOIN cuentas_bancarias B ON B.id_banco=D.id_banco 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT R.id_credito, AG.nombre FROM representantes R JOIN agrupaciones AG USING (id_grupo)) tg ON tg.id_credito = C.id_credito 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT id_persona, CONCAT(nombres,' ',apellido_paterno,' ',apellido_materno) AS NombComp FROM personas) tp ON A.id_persona = tp.id_persona  
GROUP BY YEAR(M.fecha_mov), MONTH(M.fecha_mov), P.id_persona 
HAVING -SUM(M.monto) > 15000 
ORDER BY B.id_banco, M.fecha_mov, C.id_credito
```

I think both left outer joins are causing the problem without them, the query runs neat. I'm using the left outer join part because just some instances of **representantes** table have a relation with **creditos** table, so in the case there is no relation I use the join with **personas** table.

Do you think this query can be optimized?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @simon at rcl and @Kickstart the query has been improved removing one LEFT OUTER JOIN that was not needed and removing the subquery

```
SELECT M.fecha_mov, -SUM(M.monto) monto, -SUM(M.interes) interes, -SUM(M.iva) iva, -SUM(M.capital) capital, 
B.banco, 
COALESCE(AG.nombre, CONCAT(nombres,' ',apellido_paterno,' ',apellido_materno)) nombreGrupo, 
CONCAT(nombres,' ',apellido_paterno,' ',apellido_materno) nombre, 
C.expediente, C.id_credito 
FROM movimientos M 
JOIN acreditados A ON A.id_acreditado=M.id_acreditado 
JOIN personas P ON P.id_persona=A.id_persona 
JOIN creditos C ON C.id_credito=A.id_credito 
JOIN abonos AB ON AB.id_movimiento=M.id_movimiento 
JOIN depositos_bancarios D ON D.id_deposito=AB.id_deposito 
JOIN cuentas_bancarias B ON B.id_banco=D.id_banco 
LEFT OUTER JOIN representantes R ON R.id_credito=C.id_credito
LEFT OUTER JOIN agrupaciones AG ON AG.id_grupo=R.id_grupo 
GROUP BY YEAR(M.fecha_mov), MONTH(M.fecha_mov), P.id_persona 
HAVING -SUM(M.monto) > 15000 
ORDER BY B.id_banco, M.fecha_mov, C.id_credito
```

**UPDATE**

Thank you all for your valuable tips, now I can run my query within 1 sec! I'll post my query plan as suggested, if you have any suggestion please let me know. To be honest I'm new in query plan thing.

```
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'C', 'ALL', 'PRIMARY', NULL, NULL, NULL, '888', 'Using temporary; Using filesort'
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'R', 'ref', 'fk_representantes_creditos_idx', 'fk_representantes_creditos_idx', '4', 'creabien_sacredi_dev.C.id_credito', '1', ''
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'AG', 'eq_ref', 'PRIMARY', 'PRIMARY', '4', 'creabien_sacredi_dev.R.id_grupo', '1', ''
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'A', 'ref', 'PRIMARY,FK_acreditados_personas,FK_acreditados_creditos', 'FK_acreditados_creditos', '4', 'creabien_sacredi_dev.C.id_credito', '2', ''
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'P', 'eq_ref', 'PRIMARY', 'PRIMARY', '4', 'creabien_sacredi_dev.A.id_persona', '1', ''
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'M', 'ref', 'PRIMARY,FK_movimientos_acreditados', 'FK_movimientos_acreditados', '4', 'creabien_sacredi_dev.A.id_acreditado', '10', ''
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'AB', 'ref', 'FK_abonos_depositos_bancarios,FK_abonos_movimientos', 'FK_abonos_movimientos', '8', 'creabien_sacredi_dev.M.id_movimiento', '1', ''
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'D', 'eq_ref', 'PRIMARY,FK_depositos_bancarios_cuentas_bancarias', 'PRIMARY', '8', 'creabien_sacredi_dev.AB.id_deposito', '1', ''
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'B', 'ALL', 'PRIMARY', NULL, NULL, NULL, '6', 'Using where; Using join buffer'
```

Comment: Have you checked that you are not missing any indexes?

Comment: @Bobby why do you mean by missing indexes? I'm using innoDB engine

Comment: Why are those subqueries *subqueries*? Why aren't they regular JOINs like everything else?

Comment: Post your table schema and ensure you are using indexes. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-indexes.html

Comment: @JorgeZapata Do you think that with InnoDB there's no need for indexes?

Comment: All joins are made by table's primary key, do you think I need to add more indexes?

Comment: @Strawberry do you think those subqueries could be changed by JOINs even when using the LEFT OUTER JOIN?

Comment: You can get rid of the second Left Outer Join onto personas: you are already querying that table, and can replace tp.NombComp in the coalesce with CONCAT(a.nombres,' ',a.apellido_paterno,' ',a.apellido_materno). At a minimum you need indexes on the columns mentioned in the ON part of the JOINs, in the table you are joining to: e.g. on acreditatos.id_acreditado and so on.

Comment: @simonatrcl that definitely improved the query. All columns mentioned in the JOINs are primary index. Do you know if I can get rid of the first subquery?

Comment: Doesn't look like it, as that queries a table which isn't already in the SELECT. For further improvements, you need to look at the Query Plans.

Comment: What is your query execution plan? You can run an explain plan statement and post its results here.

Comment: You may be able to change you other sub query to a pair of LEFT OUTER JOINs such as these - LEFT OUTER JOIN representantes R ON R.id_credito = C.id_credito 
LEFT OUTER JOIN agrupaciones tg ON tg.id_grupo = R.id_grupo . However this will depend on the relationships (ie, if R.id_credito is not unique and / or tg.id_grupo is not unique)

Comment: @Kickstart that's a good idea. I have a view which in fact is the same as the subquery, do you think is better to use that view instead 2 LEFT OUTER JOIN?

Comment: Thanks for your help @Rachcha, I've posted the explain statement and removed the subquery as Kickstart suggested

Comment: The view won't help. However on the explain details it seems that the join against cuentas_bancarias is not using an index. However this might just be down to a limited number of records on that table and hence mysql ignoring the manual.

Comment: @Kickstart that table just has 6 records, I think there should be no problem. The query runs too fast now, I have no error with execution time. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all comments, the answer is the following:

```
SELECT M.fecha_mov, -SUM(M.monto) monto, -SUM(M.interes) interes, -SUM(M.iva) iva, -SUM(M.capital) capital, 
B.banco, 
COALESCE(AG.nombre, CONCAT(nombres,' ',apellido_paterno,' ',apellido_materno)) nombreGrupo, 
CONCAT(nombres,' ',apellido_paterno,' ',apellido_materno) nombre, 
C.expediente, C.id_credito 
FROM movimientos M 
JOIN acreditados A ON A.id_acreditado=M.id_acreditado 
JOIN personas P ON P.id_persona=A.id_persona 
JOIN creditos C ON C.id_credito=A.id_credito 
JOIN abonos AB ON AB.id_movimiento=M.id_movimiento 
JOIN depositos_bancarios D ON D.id_deposito=AB.id_deposito 
JOIN cuentas_bancarias B ON B.id_banco=D.id_banco 
LEFT OUTER JOIN representantes R ON R.id_credito=C.id_credito
LEFT OUTER JOIN agrupaciones AG ON AG.id_grupo=R.id_grupo
GROUP BY YEAR(M.fecha_mov), MONTH(M.fecha_mov), P.id_persona 
HAVING -SUM(M.monto) > 15000 
ORDER BY B.id_banco, M.fecha_mov, C.id_credito
```